# How to use a different background for an icon

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/base-css.html#icons - I would like to reuse the icon-minus with a different background (say grey). Can I customize the existing bootstrap icon or should I look for a different icon here.

Answer (score 1):

The icons use a sprite sheet, in order to alter the color of the sprite itself you will need image manipulation software. You may want to take a look at icon fonts, these are more versatile:

http://zurb.com/playground/foundation-icons

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest you to use FontAwesome webfont icons. http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/ . It can be easily integrated with Bootstrap.